# Use a categorical variable as the color for Pairs in R

Tags: r, colors, plot

I want to create a matrix plot but using one of the categorical variables as the color. I used the following code for the matrix:

```
pairs(salesintl)
```

It gave me the matrix plot just fine (see the output [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ip8sizdxn7lkaqy/matrix_before_color.png)).

Then I revised the code to:

```
pairs(salesintl, col=salesintl$Status)
```

It returns an empty matrix plot (see output [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c6kuduot5otqkx4/matrix_after_col.png)).

It is like a empty frame with no content. `salesintl$status` is a factor with 2 layers.

What I did wrong?
Thanks,

Comment: This page includes some info on using color in the matrix plot.  I haven't tried it myself, so YMMV: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/graphics/html/pairs.html

Comment: You've used inconsistent capitalization for the `s` in `Status`... make sure you don't have a typo in your code. You're following the right basic recipe, e.g.: `pairs(matrix(runif(300), nc=3), col=sample(gl(3, 100)))`.

Comment: when i use this `pairs(~Tenure+Year.of.DOB, data = salesintl, col=salesintl$Status)`, it works, but when i test on the entire data table, the matrix became empty :(

Comment: Maybe try on incrementally larger subsets to pinpoint the problem

Comment: Also, when I use `Status` as the color, the output shows Red and Black. How do I know what color responds to which level in the factor?

Comment: Factor levels are coerced to integers, and integers 1 and 2 correspond to black and red, respectively. See `levels(salesintl$Status)` to find out which order the levels are in.

Comment: @jbaums, thanks! Is there a way to show the color legend on the graph?

Comment: Adapt this code: `pairs(iris[1:4], col=sample(2, 150, r=TRUE), upper.panel=NULL); par(xpd=NA); legend('topright', c('Black things', 'Red things'), col=1:2, pch=21, bty='n')`. If you want the upper diagonal in the SPOM, then look at `?layout` for an alternative approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you happy to use the ggplot world rather thn base R grahics, then:

```r
library(GGally)
ggpairs(salesintl, aes(color = status))
```

is the simplest expression I've found.

I also like that `ggpairs` will accept categorical variables, and gives something similar to mosaicplots (when categorical vs categorical) or boxplots (when categorical vs numeric).

[image]